# Guidance on proper ventilation for tools in a small indoor workshop

Tags: venting, air-quality

I am currently looking to set up an extra bedroom for an indoor workshop with the following:

- 3D printer, FDM and resin
- Laser engraver/cutter
- Airbrush booth
- CNC router

I have an enclosure for the 3D printer and will be building one for the laser engraver. I have watched a number of YouTube videos on workshop dust collection setups. My thought is to run PVC pipe as ducting to a window via an inline duct fan. I am thinking of using blast gates at each workstation. For the CNC router, I plan to use a regular shop vac for dust collection.

My main concern is extracting the vapors/fumes for the 3D printer, laser engraver, and airbrush booth. I found a duct fan rated at 100 CFM but want to know if that will be enough. Also, is there anything else to take into consideration?

Comment: Anything with flammable fumes (which seems quite likely based on your equipment) would need an explosion-proof fan to insure there isn't any possibility of fumes igniting or exploding.

Comment: PVC used with dust (CNC router most obvious) is subject to possible dust explosions from static electricity - metal duct is both more fireproof and less likely to spark and cause a fire or explosion.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I would be doing dust collection for the CNC router just with a shop vac. I am mostly concerned with vapors/fumes.

Comment: The problem has two parts: taking fumes out, and then taking fresh air in. If you live in a climate where it gets cold outside, you need to have a way for the clean air to get into the shop with the windows closed.

Answer (score 0):

There are tables of air movement required for spaces:

bedrooms: about 3 room air changes per hour

up to

commercial kitchen: about 40 room air changes per hour

These can be found by looking for ventilation requirements.

You need to then design the fan to achieve the necessary air flow.

Comment: I'm not looking to vent the entire room only the individual workstations with their own enclosures.

Comment: @agarza then why ask about “guidance on ventilating a small workshop”? Anyway apply the idea of what I explained.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; I have edited the title to reflect what exactly what I am trying to accomplish.